# How are fixed vs. variable length stings handled differently in VB6 UDTs?

Tags: string, vb6, user-defined-types

In VB6, I can use either fixed or variable length strings in a UDT:

```
Public Type MyRecord
    VariableLengthString As String
    FixedLengthString As String * 80
End Type
```

I would expect `FixedLengthString` to allocate 160 bytes in the UDT, and if I had an array of these UDT's, the fixed length string data is inline.

What's going on with `VariableLengthString`?  Is it allocated on the heap?

Therefore, if I do this:

```
Dim record1 As MyRecord
Dim record2 As MyRecord
record1.VariableLengthString = "a"
record2 = record1
```

... obviously `record2.VariableLengthString` will be `"a"`.  But, if I do this:

```
record2.VariableLengthString = "b"
```

... then what is the value of `record1.VariableLengthString`?

**Update**: It turns out that the result is still `"a"`, which means the string is copied.  So is it not on the heap?

My test code:

```
record1.VariableLengthString = "a"
record2 = record1
? record2.VariableLengthString
a
record2.VariableLengthString = "b"
? record1.VariableLengthString
a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically "as string" allocates a BSTR in VB6. OLE (the technology underlying VB6) handles BSTRs in special ways including maintaining a cache to make string manipulation faster. This [article on String Manipulation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221105.aspx) in MSDN explains it more detail. The UDT points to a BSTR stucture that is basically a 32bit length field followed by the characters of the string. It is Unicode aware. The space allocated to a BSTR is 4 bytes + the number of bytes to store the characters. So it is variable not fixed like Fixed Length String.

Comment: This is the correct answer, so long as you add the following: while BSTR's are not immutable, within VB6, Strings likely do function in an immutable way, so when you copy `record1` to `record2`, you're copying the pointer.  However, You could potentially pass the BSTR to a native function which could call `SysReAllocString` on it, or manipulate it in-place, which would cause both copies to be modified.  So it's not guaranteed that you couldn't corrupt `record1`'s field by fiddling with `record2`'s field.

Comment: @Scott VB6 strings are immutable, but no-one ever got confused by that. IMHO that's because that area of the language and the API were well designed. I've never seen (or heard of) any odd behaviour from both copies of a structure sharing the same pointer. By "native" function do you mean calling the Windows API?